# So You Want to Attend Movie Night

Tags: discussion, community, community-event

Given that we're a few Movie Nights in (to the point where I've stopped numbering them), I think it's time we nail some things down.

1. **Do not talk to me about Fight Club**: Seriously, I've heard it all.
2. **Movie Night will always take place on a weekend**: This is only something that came up for the last Movie Night. As I was looking at the results for the scheduling poll, I realized that only one of the dates was on Saturday. This was my mistake and all future Movie Nights will be on Saturdays barring specific circumstances. Please inform me if the scheduling poll shows differently.
3. **Rabb.it**: We use Rabb.it to watch movies together. We have a regular room [here](https://rabb.it/yuuki). Account sign-ups are not necessary, you can just pick up a nickname upon visiting the page. There is also a chat window that you can open and discuss the movie with others who are also watching. Be aware the standard video quality defaults to Low. I am not sure if Standard or High Definition costs money, but previous Movie Nights have indicated to me that this is not the case.
4. **Don't be a jerk while watching the movie**: This one is a bit broad, but rule of thumb is basically to not say anything in the Rabb.it chatroom that you wouldn't in The Bridge (which I'll admit is pretty broad).
5. **Sunday showings are by request**: While Saturday showings have a predetermined time, Sunday showings are flexible by virtue of being make-up showings for people who missed Saturday. Please ping me in The Bridge chatroom to start a showing if you want to attend, I will not setup Sunday showings unless asked.

[Here's a survey for Movie Night attendees](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScyQRjwDM-55rmAOQoGvI1bGGOJLvTTA-ku8wAHiepHd9GKmQ/viewform). It's not required to be filled out to show up for Movie Night, but I will be looking at the timezone portion when considering scheduling.

I've also created an events calendar. I'll be using this mostly to list important dates for Movie Night such as decision deadlines and scheduling. [The Google Calendar can be found here](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=8gtkr34lhgm3rgprrcer6ku26s%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/Chicago) and you should be able to add it to your own Google Calendar. If you don't use Google Calendar, you should still be able to view it in your browser.

Comment: I've said it before, but I want to say it again: Thanks for hosting these movie nights. They're a lot of fun, and I really look forward to them.

Comment: The rabb.it room is locked.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy It is locked because there's no Movie Night on. Whenever we have Movie Night, I'll unlock the room.

Answer (score 13):

## So You Want to Suggest a Movie

Movie Night is a community event, everyone can suggest and vote on movies. Here's a nice format to follow when suggesting a movie:

[image]

- Label your post as a suggestion (to distinguish it from a decision).
- Try to include a poster and a blurb, it helps to give some background on the movie.
- Post helpful links such as trailers, reviews, and content warnings. The latter is especially important because not everyone is okay with all movie content.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to the meta, is answering your own question normal?

Comment: This isn't so much a question as a post describing rules and stuff for a community event.

Comment: @Alex You are allowed to answer your own question anytime you like, whether it be on main or meta. This question is special though - Yukki is the coordinator of these evens, and as such he asked and answered his own question in order to convey the rules.

Comment: @angussidney Ok thanks

Comment: Metaception!  Meta Within Meta!