# Bridge Movie Night - June 2016

Tags: discussion, community, community-event, movie-night

See ground rules and guidelines here: [So You Want to Attend Movie Night](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/so-you-want-to-attend-movie-night)

It's summertime and that means summer break. For those of you in school, enjoy your time off and try to catch a movie with everyone in June. [Pick a day you're available](http://www.strawpoll.me/10164343), vote or suggest your favorite movies below, and have fun!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Movie Decision

[image]

#### Zootopia

Time: [June 11, 11:00 PM UTC-0](http://goo.gl/5O8TP0)

Location: [Bridge Movie Theatre](http://rabb.it/yuuki)

Comment: Yay! This is going to be awesome.

Comment: Have you considered making a BMN Google Calendar (or some importable equivalent)?

Comment: @fredley [Yuuki tried a bit](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=30172543#30172543) but in the end, I ended up making this: https://sharing.calendar.live.com/calendar/private/80594819-8f61-4af0-a8c7-624dfc36ac76/54620bc8-7ffa-4f86-aa2c-f5a55a1f3715/cid-672b92ae519c2850/index.html

Answer (score 11):

## Movie Suggestion: Zootopia

[image: Zootopia Poster featuring a lot of the characters from the movie walking down the street]

Officer Judy Hopps is the first bunny on the Zootopia police force and she jumps headlong into her first case. However, she must team up with scam-artist Nick Wilde to solve the mystery.

The movie is released on June 7

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWM0ct-OLsM) | [Rotten Tomatoes (98%)](http://rottentomatoes.com/m/zootopia/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://imdb.com/title/tt2948356/parentalguide)

Comment: Where are you getting information on the release date? As far as I know, there hasn't been any official announcements.

Comment: @Yuuki http://movies.disney.com/zootopia

Comment: Okay then, sounds good. If this is the most upvoted suggestion and June 4 is the scheduled Movie Night date as well, this will likely be selected as the August Movie Night showing (basically what we did with Big Hero 6).

Answer (score 6):

## Movie Suggestion

[image]

### Ex Machina

A young, brilliant programmer wins the chance to spend a week at the house of his CEO. He soon discovers that the house is a laboratory where his employee is conducting tests on Artificial Intelligence and he's supposed to administer a Turing test on a humanoid robot named Ava.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYGzRB4Pnq8) | [Rotten Tomatoes (92%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/ex_machina/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated R)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0470752/parentalguide)

Comment: Self note: watch this later if it doesn't get picked.

Comment: This is a great movie but has some pretty explicit stuff in it toward the end. Just FYI.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune is there any age restriction for Bridge Movie Night? I couldn't find any in [Yuuki's presentation](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11441/23609) and, given that there's another R-rated movie among the suggestions (Mad Max), I thought that there was no problem about this

Comment: @Kappei well the only person that doesn't fit R that attends movie nights is me and well, I'll go ahead and post it no matter the age ratings. (unless stack says that we shouldn't organize movie nights watching R rated movies)

Comment: @Kappei AFAIK, there is not an age restriction per-se, I just wanted to make sure that the voters/potential viewers are aware of it. I personally don't have a problem with it and like I said, it's a fantastic movie with interesting themes. If anyone is concerned about the explicitness, I encourage them to check out the parent guide you linked in the post.

Comment: Basically, R ratings is why I ask people to post a parental guide. Not all R's are equal and what one person can stand in an R-rated movie, another person cannot.

Comment: I've watched this and it was quite disappointing. What a weak closure.

Comment: @badp just watched and indeed a weak closure.

Answer (score 6):

### Movie Suggestion: *Deadpool*

[image: Deadpool]

Via [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/deadpool/):

> Based upon Marvel Comics' most unconventional anti-hero, DEADPOOL tells the origin story of former Special Forces operative turned mercenary Wade Wilson, who after being subjected to a rogue experiment that leaves him with accelerated healing powers, adopts the alter ego Deadpool. Armed with his new abilities and a dark, twisted sense of humor, Deadpool hunts down the man who nearly destroyed his life.

[**Trailer**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SB0YRDkUlnk) | Tomato/Audience Score: [**83%/92%**](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/deadpool/) | Advisory: [**R**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/parentalguide) | Runtime: **108 min**

Genre: [action](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action) [adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure) [comedy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comedy)

Comment: I actually haven't seen this, and would like to.  Would have seen it in theatres with some friends if I hadn't been sick.

Comment: Great movie. Watched it before but would love to watch again.

Answer (score 4):

## Movie Suggestion

[image]

### Captain America: The Winter Soldier

After waking up in the modern era and joining the Avengers, Steve Rogers (also known as Captain America) works for S.H.I.E.L.D. under the direction of Nicholas Fury. When a mission turns up some suspicious dealings, Cap goes under the radar as he discovers a startling secret behind the founding of S.H.I.E.L.D. and finds that he can't trust anyone. Now it's up to him to build to a team to save the world from a threat it never saw coming.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvD6clUAWdA) | [Rotten Tomatoes (89%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/captain_america_the_winter_soldier_2014/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG-13)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843866/parentalguide)

Answer (score 3):

## Movie Suggestion: Mad Max: Fury Road

[image: Movie Poster]

A woman rebels against a tyrannical ruler in postapocalyptic Australia in search for her home-land with the help of a group of female prisoners, a psychotic worshipper, and a drifter named Max.

[Trailer](http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi3047862297) | [Rotten Tomatoes (97%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/mad_max_fury_road/) | [IMDB 8.1 (Rated R)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392190/)

Comment: Also, yes, it is on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/Mad_Max_4_Fury_Road?id=jUHrve5oUQk&hl=en)

Comment: This is the best action movie I have ever seen.

Answer (score 3):

## Movie Suggestion: Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy

[image]

Mere seconds before the Earth is to be demolished by an alien construction crew, journeyman Arthur Dent is swept off the planet by his friend Ford Prefect, a researcher penning a new edition of "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy."

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbGNcoB2Y4I)  | [Rotten Tomatoes (60%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/hitchhikers_guide_to_the_galaxy/)  | [IMDB (PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371724/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

Comment: SMDH if we don't watch this, Mad Max or Ex Machina.

Comment: Best book/radio play ever, re-reading it ATM. Movie is pretty good

Comment: Fun movie, but the [miniseries](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(TV_series)) was a lot more faithful to the books.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and listen to the original BBC radio series. This is a pale tribute.

Comment: @fredley is there a good way to find that?

Comment: @AshleyNunn http://www.induceddyslexia.com/hitchhiker.htm

Answer (score 2):

## Movie Suggestion

[image]

### Star Wars: The Force Awakens

It's been 30 years since the original trilogy, when Luke Skywalker and the Rebellion defeated the Empire. But it's not the happy ever after they hoped for as The First Order has risen from the ashes of the Galactic Empire, seeking once more to dominate the galaxy. Follow new heroes Rey, a scavenger from the planet Jakku, and Finn, a former stormtrooper, as they search for a way to bring peace to the galaxy once and for all.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGbxmsDFVnE) | [Rotten Tomatoes (92%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/star_wars_episode_vii_the_force_awakens/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG-13)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/parentalguide)

Answer (score 1):

## Movie Suggestion

[image]

### Legend

Suave, charming and volatile, Reggie Kray and his unstable twin brother Ronnie start to leave their mark on the London underworld in the 1960s. Using violence to get what they want, the siblings orchestrate robberies and murders while running nightclubs and protection rackets. With police Detective Leonard "Nipper" Read hot on their heels, the brothers continue their rapid rise to power and achieve tabloid notoriety.

[Trailer](https://youtu.be/ey7S4hko_Mc) | [Rotten Tomatoes (62%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/legend_2015) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated R)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3569230/parentalguide)

Answer (score 0):

## Movie Suggestion

[image]

### Seven Samurai

A samurai answers a village's request for protection after he falls on hard times. The town needs protection from bandits, so the samurai gathers six others to help him teach the people how to defend themselves, and the villagers provide the soldiers with food. A giant battle occurs when 40 bandits attack the village.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMDkvS6sej0) | [Rotten Tomatoes (100%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/seven_samurai_1956/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (PG 13)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047478/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg) | [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Samurai)

Answer (score -2):

## Movie Suggestion

[image]

### Maleficent

A vengeful fairy is driven to curse an infant princess, only to discover that the child may be the one person who can restore peace to their troubled land.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pgmFAOgm5E) | [Rotten Tomatoes (49%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/maleficent_2014) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1587310/parentalguide)