# Bridge Movie Night - August 2016

Tags: discussion, community-event, movie-night

[So You Want To Attend Movie Night](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/so-you-want-to-attend-movie-night)

The attendance for Movie Night earlier this month was great, I really enjoyed seeing all of you in the chat room, talking, and having fun watching the movie. You all know the drill, [pick dates that you are available](http://www.strawpoll.me/10623731), suggest movies, and vote on your favorites. Don't be afraid to suggest old movies, feel free to suggest anything you feel that everyone would enjoy.

This month's movie decision might come a bit late, if I can't get to it by the end of the month, I'll have someone else make the decision post for me.

Comment: Thanks for doing these events.

Comment: It's neat to see these, even though I never actually attend. If I ever did, I would suggest A Boy and His Dog, aka Fallout the Movie.

Comment: When is the next movie night? I might want to suggest the secret life of pets.

Comment: @Alex, this is for the next movie night, it will be sometime in August depending on which date is chosen. The next one after that is October I think

Comment: @Dragonrage ok then I might ask for that movie then

Comment: Next movie night, would it be possible to enable the multiple choice option within Strawpoll?  For instance,  I can make multiple dates but choose the first simply because it is the one closest.  Allowing multiple choice might make it more representative of the common interest.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert Oh, did I not enable multiple choice? I'm fairly sure I did...

Comment: @Yuuki Ah!  Apologies, it appears you actually did and it just wasn't appearing like it on my phone.  Glad you've got everything covered =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Movie Decision

[image: 1]

### Deadpool

Sorry for the late decision, I have been caught up with not-being-able-to-Internet issues. The results of the date polling are as follows:

[image]

And so August's Bridge Movie Night will take place on [**Saturday, August 6, 2016 at 11:00 PM UTC-0**](http://time.is/1100PM_6_Aug_2016_in_UTC?Bridge_Movie_Night_-_August_2016). Now, I realize that this will be our first R-rated movie and as such, it will set a precedent for future R-rated Movie Nights. I want to be absolutely, doubly clear here:

#### Deadpool is an R-rated movie. It has an R rating from the MPAA (Motion Picture Association of America). This means it has content that almost definitely is not suitable for children. People under 17 years of age, this means you.

I know there was a [parental guide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/parentalguide) linked in the movie suggestion, so I will be concise here: *Deadpool* has been rated R due to thematic elements such as "sex & nudity", "violence & gore", "profanity", "alcohol/drugs/smoking", "frightening/intense scenes". And having watched this movie before, I can assure that all of these elements are present in substantial quantity, this is not one of those "rated R because they cursed three times" movies.

I know that I have repeated my warnings perhaps a bit incessantly both here and in the Bridge, but I just want to make sure that we do R-rated Movie Nights properly. R-rated movies should be acceptable viewings for Movie Night but there is *always* the question of suitable content. So I personally feel that the best middle ground is to show them but talk your ear off about the content warnings so you know exactly what you're getting into.

The take home for you Movie Night regulars is this: please don't feel that R-rated movies are unwelcome, just be aware that not everyone views all content equally. I hope that future Movie Nights will continue to have suggestions for R-rated movies and that we may watch some of them.

Answer (score 12):

## Movie Suggestion: Mad Max: Fury Road

[image]

A woman rebels against a tyrannical ruler in postapocalyptic Australia in search for her home-land with the help of a group of female prisoners, a psychotic worshipper, and a drifter named Max.

[Trailer](http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi3047862297) | [Rotten Tomatoes (97%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/mad_max_fury_road/) | [IMDB 8.1 (Rated R)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392190/)

Comment: This movie won *six* Oscars *and* is entertaining.

Comment: WITNESS ME (watch this movie during movie night)

Answer (score 12):

### Movie Suggestion: *Deadpool*

[image: Deadpool]

Via [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/deadpool/):

> Based upon Marvel Comics' most unconventional anti-hero, DEADPOOL tells the origin story of former Special Forces operative turned mercenary Wade Wilson, who after being subjected to a rogue experiment that leaves him with accelerated healing powers, adopts the alter ego Deadpool. Armed with his new abilities and a dark, twisted sense of humor, Deadpool hunts down the man who nearly destroyed his life.

[**Trailer**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SB0YRDkUlnk) | Tomato/Audience Score: [**83%/92%**](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/deadpool/) | Advisory: [**R**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/parentalguide) | Runtime: **108 min**

Genre: [action](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action) [adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure) [comedy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comedy)

Idea credit: @[krazer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11568/127901) from last movie night

Comment: All voters please be aware that despite the costumed character on the poster, *Deadpool* is most definitely an R-rated movie. There is nothing wrong with this, but let this be your one warning because I will not brook complaints about unsuitable content at Movie Night: that's why I have everyone provide a parental guide, it's for you to read and see what you're comfortable with.

Comment: It's not just R. It's super-R. Filthy. *Hilariously* filthy.

Answer (score 9):

## Movie Suggestion: John Carpenter's *They Live*

[image: Movie Poster]

A homeless drifter discovers a reason for the ever-widening gap between the rich and the poor: a conspiracy by non-human aliens who have infiltrated American society in the guise of wealthy yuppies. With the help of special sunglasses that reveal the aliens' true faces and their subliminal messages ("marry and reproduce," "submit to authority"), our hero tries to stop the invasion.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJC4R1uXDaE) | [Rotten Tomatoes (83%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/they_live) | [IMDB 7.3 (Rated R)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096256/)

Answer (score 4):

## Pokémon 2000

[image]

Comment: Yesss! Still remember this movie. Epic.

Comment: fredley , pls .

Answer (score -7):

## Movie Suggestion: It's Alive (1974)

[image: Movie Poster]

Heavily pregnant Lenore Davis tells her husband, Frank, that she is in labor. They leave their eleven year-old son Chris with their friend Charley and they head to the Community Hospital. Lenore feels that something is wrong...

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aD9wL0ffxqY) | [Rotten Tomatoes (69%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1010793-its_alive/) | [IMDB 5.8](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071675/) | [USA:PG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_picture_rating_system#United_States) / [UK:15](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/what-classification/15) - [Parental Guide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071675/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg) | [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Alive_(1974_film))