# Movie Night - October 2016

Tags: discussion, community-event, movie-night

The summer blockbuster season may be over, but Movie Night season is year-round! With all the stress of heading back to school, taking your kids back to school, or just work, you should kick back and relax with the rest of Arqade at our bimonthly Movie Night. [Just pick a Saturday you're available](http://www.strawpoll.me/11195250) and enjoy a fun stress-free night of movies (or movie, rather) with friends.

For more information, please see [So You Want To Attend Movie Night](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/so-you-want-to-attend-movie-night)

Comment: Yay! I love these

Comment: Is the movie showing also via Rabb.it?

Comment: @Riley yep, it is.

Comment: @arda Neat, thanks for the info.

Comment: So which weekend is this happening?  The strawpoll right now says it's the last weekend, but you don't say so explicitly anywhere.

Comment: @MBraedley My bad, I'll edit the decision post right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Movie Decision

[image]

#### Disney's The Jungle Book

We'll be watching the 2016 remake of *The Jungle Book* on [October 29 at 11:00 PM UTC-0](http://time.is/1100PM_29_Oct_2016_in_UTC?Bridge_Movie_Night_-_October_2016) in the [Bridge Movie Theatre](http://rabb.it/yuuki). I'll do an announcement in [The Bridge chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) a few minutes or so ahead of time as well as keep you up-to-date if anything comes up.

But *"wait a minute, Yuuki,"* you say, *"aren't the top two movie suggestions tied?* And you'd be correct! Which is why I'm happy to announce...

## MOVIE NIGHT DOUBLE FEATURE XTREME

[image]

We'll also be showing *The Incredibles*! After *The Jungle Book* showing concludes, we'll have a rare Movie Night double showing with

[image]

*"But Yuuki,"* you say, *"I don't have enough time in the day to watch **two** movies. I have a life!"* Well, I've got you covered there. Similar to what we did with *Guardians of the Galaxy* and *Big Hero 6* for our second Movie Night, there will be a showing for *The Incredibles* next month! [A scheduling poll is already up](http://www.strawpoll.me/11356830) and results will be tallied when we start Movie Night later this month.

Comment: +1, good use of a kingdom of loathing gif

Comment: ***ENSURE!!!***

Answer (score 8):

### Movie Suggestion: *THE JUNGLE BOOK*

[image: THE JUNGLE BOOK]

Via [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3040964/):

> After a threat from the tiger Shere Khan forces him to flee the jungle, a man-cub named Mowgli embarks on a journey of self discovery with the help of panther, Bagheera, and free spirited bear, Baloo.

[**Trailer**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqmUoteadZI) | Tomato/Audience Score: [**95%/88%**](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_jungle_book_2016/) | Advisory: [**PG**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3040964/parentalguide) | Runtime: **106 min**

Genre: [action](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action) [adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure) [drama](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drama) [family](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family)

Comment: I did not realize this remake was getting high praise. +1

Answer (score 7):

## Movie Suggestion: The Incredibles

[image: 1]]

I'm sure everyone is familiar with this movie, but if you're not then it's a film by Pixar about retired super heroes. Considering it's made by Pixar means saying "it's great" is kind of redundant, but it's often considered one of Pixars *best* movies, which is  high praise. Summary from Rotten Tomatoes:

> Once one of the world's top masked crime fighters, Bob Parr--known to all as "Mr. Incredible"--fought evil and saved lives on a daily basis. But now fifteen years later, Bob and his wife--a famous superhero in her own right--have adopted civilian identities and retreated to the suburbs to live normal lives with their three kids. Now he's a clock-punching insurance claims adjuster fighting boredom and a bulging waistline. Itching to get back into action, Bob gets his chance when a mysterious communication summons him to a remote island for a top-secret assignment.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZbzbC9285I) | [Rotten Tomatoes (97%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/incredibles/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317705/)

Comment: "2004" I feel old.

Comment: I love this movie!

Answer (score 5):

## Movie Suggestion: Captain America: Civil War

[image: 1]]

It's been a year since the Avengers defeated Ultron and the superheroes of the world are starting to lose that rosy-eyed appeal. After an intervention gone wrong in Nigeria, the stage is set for a confrontation.

Steve believes that after the SHIELD debacle in *Captain America: Winter Soldier*, governments and huge shadowy agencies can't be trusted with the protection of the common man. Tony, on the other hand, fresh from his failure with the Ultron Intiative, believes that individuals including himself need to be put in check before their arrogance does more harm than good.

And as the superheroes of the world pick their sides, the infamous assassin, the Winter Soldier, is still at large...

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnv__ogkt0M) | [Rotten Tomatoes (90%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/captain_america_civil_war/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG-13)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498820/parentalguide)

Comment: @GnomeSlice I haven't seen this one yet.

Answer (score 5):

## **Movie Suggestion: The Babadook**

[image]

"A single mother, plagued by the violent death of her husband, battles with her son's fear of a monster lurking in the house, but soon discovers a sinister presence all around her."

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szaLnKNWC-U) | [Rotten Tomatoes (98%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_babadook/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Not Rated)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2321549/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

Comment: I've not seen it, and I doubt I'd make the movie night, but c'mon. It's October. It should be a scary movie.

Comment: This is a pretty good movie.

Comment: I disagree, this movie was pretty weak, especially the ending. I don't know how it has such high marks on rotten tomatoes.

Answer (score 3):

Actione. Terrore. Suspenso. SPIDER!

[image]

### The Italian Spiderman

> Have you ever wondered what would happen if an Italian producer took quaaludes, stumbled into a theater, and saw the first 5 minutes of spider man 2? Well wonder no more because Italian Spider-Man is here to haunt your dreams with meteors, snake men, and macchiatos. Let's do it PussyCat!

[Trailer (unsubbed)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhHhXukovMU) | [IMDB - 8.0/10](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2705436/?ref_=nv_sr_1) | **40 minutes**

Comment: Wait did they actually make a full length version

Comment: "BleckJeck! Mrrahhh!"

Comment: I'm Italian, and I've never heard about it! Also, that "Italian" used in the trailer sounds so wrong that's actually funny.

Answer (score 3):

## Movie Suggestion: Star Wars: The Force Awakens

[image: Star Wars: The Force Awakens Poster]

> Three decades after the defeat of the Galactic Empire, a new threat arises. The First Order attempts to rule the galaxy and only a ragtag group of heroes can stop them, along with the help of the Resistance.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGbxmsDFVnE) | [Rotten Tomatoes (92%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/star_wars_episode_vii_the_force_awakens/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG-13)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/parentalguide)

Answer (score 1):

## Movie Suggestion: Mascots

*Film will be released direct to Netflix on October 13*.

About Mascots:
Mascots is a new comedy from Christopher Guest, director of Waiting for Guffman and Best in Show. Starring many of his regular troupe of actors, this latest film takes place in the ultra-competitive world of sports mascots where they compete for the most prestigious award in their field, the Gold Fluffy.

The Netflix original film stars Jane Lynch, Parker Posey, Fred Willard, Ed Begley, Jr., Christopher Moynihan, Don Lake, Brad Williams, Zach Woods, Chris O’Dowd, Susan Yeagley, Sarah Baker, Tom Bennett, Kerry Godliman, Bob Balaban, Jennifer Coolidge, Michael Hitchcock, Maria Blasucci, John Michael Higgins, and Jim Piddock. The film was written by Christopher Guest & Jim Piddock and produced by Karen Murphy. Mascots will launch globally on Netflix on 13 October 2016

Comment: And now I remember why I don't bother.

Answer (score 1):

## Movie Suggestion: Warcraft

[image: 1]]

The peaceful realm of Azeroth stands on the brink of war as its civilization faces a fearsome race of invaders: Orc warriors fleeing their dying home to colonize another. As a portal opens to connect the two worlds, one army faces destruction and the other faces extinction. From opposing sides, an unlikely set of heroes are set on a collision course that will decide the fate of their families, their people and their home. So begins a spectacular saga of power and sacrifice in which war has many faces, and everyone fights for something.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Rxoz13Bthc) | [Rotten Tomatoes (28% - 76%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/warcraft/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Score: 7.2 - Rated PG-13)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0803096/parentalguide) | [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/Warcraft?id=75bQH2VSwvY)

Comment: Now that you've reminded me it actually *did* come out, I really want to see what they ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

## Movie Suggestion

[image]

### Heathers

Veronica Sawyer, a brainy, beautiful teenage misfit who hustles her way into the most powerful and ruthless clique at Westerberg High: the Heathers.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTmpKgocyYg) | [Rotten Tomatoes (95%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/heathers/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated 18)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097493/parentalguide) | [The Musical](http://heathersthemusical.com/)

Answer (score -2):

## Movie Suggestion: The Angry Birds Movie

[image: 1]]

This is a dark horse pick, but it's personally one of my favorite movies of the year. Good animation, a strange plot, and undertones of issues such as immigration and western power dynamics will keep your interest throughout.

> An island populated entirely by happy, flightless birds or almost entirely. In this paradise, Red, a bird with a temper problem, speedy Chuck, and the volatile Bomb have always been outsiders. But when the island is visited by mysterious green piggies, it’s up to these unlikely outcasts to figure out what the pigs are up to.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cmd2veJheYY) | [Rotten Tomatoes (43%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_angry_birds_movie) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1985949/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes, I thought this movie was good