# Movie Night - December 2016

Tags: discussion, community-event, movie-night

[Yuuki is pretty busy adulting lately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xThU4tfmMg), so I figured I'd step up and make the December Movie Night post for him. [Just pick a Saturday you're available](http://www.strawpoll.me/11704558) and enjoy a snow covered movie night with friends.

For more information, please see [So You Want To Attend Movie Night](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/so-you-want-to-attend-movie-night)

Comment: When you are counting votes for dates, remove a vote from the 17th. I won't be able to make it since things came up.

Comment: Locked for science

Answer (score 10):

## Filmnachtentscheidung:Diehard

[image]

<strike>The</strike> Die votes are in <strike>and</strike> und we'll be watching <strike>Die</strike> <strike>The</strike> *Die Hard* again for our December Movie Night. <strike>And</strike> Und after looking at the scheduling poll...

[image]

Movie Night will be taking place on the 10th of December. Bring your popcorn <strike>and</strike> und, given <strike>the</strike> die season, some eggnog!

Comment: Feature request: Make a subscribable calendar to which Movie nights are added.

Answer (score 5):

## DIE HARD

Did you know that in Germany, Die Hard (or "The Hard") is screened at midnight of new years eve on nearly every channel?

[image]

> Now I have a machine gun
> Ho Ho Ho

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095016/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 92%](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/die_hard/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qxBXm7ZUTM)

<sup>Yes, this was selected last year. So?</sup>

Comment: I've yet to actually see this movie.

Answer (score 5):

### Movie Suggestion: *Finding Dory*

[image: Finding Dory]

Via [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2277860/):

> The friendly but forgetful blue tang fish begins a search for her long-lost parents, and everyone learns a few things about the real meaning of family along the way.

[**Trailer**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKJA-VLpiCo) | Tomato/Audience Score: [**94%/86%**](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/finding_dory) | Advisory: [**PG**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2277860/parentalguide) | Runtime: **97 min**

Genre: [action](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/action) [adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure) [comedy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comedy) [family](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family)

Answer (score 3):

## A Christmas Story

[image]

> In the 1940's, in the town of Hammond, 9-year-old Ralphie wants one thing for Christmas -- an official Red Ryder BB rifle. When he asks his mother for the BB gun for Christmas, she says, "No, you'll shoot your eye out". When he writes an essay about it at school his teacher gives him a C+ with a note saying "You'll shoot your eye out." Next he asks Santa for the gun, Santa's response is familiar, he says, "You'll shoot your eye out, kid." Ralph fears that he'll never get the BB gun for Christmas. But there may be a surprise in store for him.

An instant Christmas classic, complete with a leg lamp.

[Trailer](https://youtu.be/uvMLfSQrHKE) | [Rotten Tomatoes (89%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1004151-christmas_story) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG, but it was the '80s)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085334/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

Answer (score 3):

## Gremlins

[image]

> A boy inadvertently breaks three important rules concerning his new pet and unleashes a horde of malevolently mischievous monsters on a small town.

A quality movie that everyone forgets is actually a Christmas movie.

[Trailer](http://www.imdb.com/video/imdb/vi1706295833?playlistId=tt0087363&ref_=tt_ov_vi) | [Rotten Tomatoes (85%)](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/gremlins/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG, but it was also the '80s)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087363/parentalguide)

Comment: What are those things in Gremlins called?

Comment: @Colin What things?