# Bridge Movie Night - December 2017

Tags: discussion, community-event, movie-night

So it seems that we've missed a few nights here and there. Given the relative delay in announcing this one, I'm unfortunately going to have to skip the step where I poll you all on scheduling and just declare that we're doing this one on the 23rd. Make your recommendations and vote them!

[Look here if this will be your first Movie Night (or if you've forgotten some stuff, I don't blame you given that it's been awhile).](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/so-you-want-to-attend-movie-night)

Answer (score 11):

Die Hard.

Comment: Ah yes, a classic Christmas movie. :)

Comment: If Die Hard wins again (as it did last December), it will mean I miss another chance to finally actually see Die Hard.